# INSERT into another table, and then DELETE from the source table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How can I delete the first 18 rows (sorted by FIELD1) from the "pippo" table, and then insert THE SAME 18 rows in another clone-table called minnie?

The following code extracts the first 18 rows ordering by FIELD1, and then deletes them:

```
WITH  q AS
        (
        SELECT TOP 18 *
        FROM    pippo
        ORDER BY FIELD1 ASC /* You may want to add ORDER BY here */
        )
DELETE
FROM    q
```

How can I insert the same 18 rows into the minnie table, before deleting them?

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

Comment: Why don't you just first insert the rows in the new table and delete them afterwards in the old table?

Comment: How can I realize this??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
WITH  q AS
        (
        SELECT TOP 18 *
        FROM    pippo
        ORDER BY FIELD1 ASC /* You may want to add ORDER BY here */
        )
DELETE
FROM    q
OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO TableNew
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to, you can nest the `delete` inside a `select` for an `insert` query:

```
declare @t1 table (Field1 int not null)
declare @t2 table (Field1 int not null)

insert into @t1 (Field1) select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) from sys.objects

;with First18 as (
    select top 18 * from @t1 order by Field1
)
insert into @t2 (Field1)
select * from 
    (
    delete from First18 output deleted.Field1) t
```